# Почему oracle distributed transaction не блокирует таблицы?

Tags: java, oracle

Вот такой распределенный комит по 2х фазному протоколу:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws SQLException, XAException {
    OracleXADataSource dataSource1 = new OracleXADataSource();
    dataSource1.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE");
    dataSource1.setUser("system");
    dataSource1.setPassword("111");

    OracleXADataSource dataSource2 = new OracleXADataSource();
    dataSource2.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/XE");
    dataSource2.setUser("alex");
    dataSource2.setPassword("111");

    XAConnection xaConnection = dataSource1.getXAConnection();
    XAResource res = xaConnection.getXAResource();
    Connection connection = xaConnection.getConnection();
    FooXid xid1 = new FooXid(1);
    res.start(xid1, XAResource.TMNOFLAGS);
    connection.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (1)");
    res.end(xid1, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);

    XAConnection xaConnection2 = dataSource2.getXAConnection();
    XAResource res2 = xaConnection2.getXAResource();
    Connection connection2 = xaConnection2.getConnection();
    FooXid xid2 = new FooXid(2);
    res2.start(xid2, XAResource.TMNOFLAGS);
    connection2.createStatement().execute("INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES (2)");
    res2.end(xid2, XAResource.TMSUCCESS);

    int verdict = res.prepare(xid1);
    int verdict2 = res2.prepare(xid2);

    if (verdict == XAResource.XA_OK)
        res.commit(xid1, false);//breakpoint1

    if (verdict2 == XAResource.XA_OK)
        res2.commit(xid2, false);//breakpoint2

    xaConnection.close();
    xaConnection2.close();

    connection.close();
    connection2.close();
}
```

когда я дебагером дохожу до //breakpoint1 или //breakpoint2 и пробую выбрать из таблицы значения *SELECT*, то запрос проходит.
Но ведь таблица должна быть заблокированной согласно документации!

Comment: я не работал с ораклом, но нормальный движок никогда таблицу не блокирует. он блокирует записи. кроме того, очень многое зависит от isolation level, если он не serializable.

Comment: @Etki а как же без блокирования таблицы оракл может быть уверен,что не произойдет чтения данных(грязных) во время распределенного комита? Тоесть мы читаем старые данные в 1 таблицу, котогда во 2й закомичены новые данные

Comment: А у вас это запрещено текущим isolation level ?

Comment: А зачем вам вообще нужно блокирование таблиц. В оракле обычно все делается без блокировок. Есть конечно отдельный оператор "lock table" ...

Comment: @Mike все, понял. оракл по-умолчанию блокирует таблицу на изменение ее